# Is there any way to fix a hinge pulled out of particle board cabinet door?

Tags: repair, cabinets

I hit my head on the open door cabinet over the sink, yet again, and slammed the door shut in anger.  Adding insult to injury, the whole hinge pulled out of the particle board and took a big chunk of the door with it: [Photo of damage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wF9pt.jpg)

[image]

Is there any way to fix it?  I know these are terrible cabinets, but replacing them isn't in the plans.

Comment: You could remove your cabinet doors. They're in the way of access to your dishes, and they hit you on the head, and they break easily. Stupid doors.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Particle board is generally pretty glue-able. Apply wood glue to the raw particle board and clamp the two pieces together overnight.

Comment: Particle board tends to decompress a little when it gets split apart like that. You're going to have to shave a little bit out of the joint to get it to sit flush again.

Comment: Agree, glue and clamp.  good advice Scott

Comment: I (finally) glued it with some epoxy, clamped it up well, and it looks good as new (from the outside) and works fine.  Thanks!

Comment: Have similar problem but in small area. Will the repair last if use ELMERS Carpenter's Wood Glue instead of epoxy?

Comment: @Riga probably be fine.  But if it fails, Elmers is water-soluble. Just wet it a lot, keep it wet, stiff-brush away the glue, let it dry very thoroughly like over 2 days, then epoxy it.  Epoxy is as good as it gets.

Comment: @Harper used Elmers and so far so good. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Those hinges look like they'll tolerate being moved, so you could make a cosmetic repair to the particleboard and move your hinge down a few inches to undisrupted door.

Answer (score 0):

Flip it, drill new holes for hinges and hanging and then patch, sand, and stain the damaged side so looks good as the face of your cabinet.